Tikz: On straight lines moving balls on a circle inside a regular polygon
I want to draw  something like this 
 
with n/2 balls in a regular n-polygon.
At the intersections with of the small circle inside C with the diagonals D
% Problem here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\path[name intersections={of=C and D, name=S}];
\coordinate[label=\k] (S\k) at (S-1); 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

I saw that it is sometimes S-1, sometimes S-2.
That means: if I set allways S-1 (or S-2) the picture becomes incorrect; because one or more balls moves to the origin.

What could I do?
\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\R{2cm}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\r{0.5*\R}
\def\n{6}
%\def\w{33}% test

\foreach \w in {15,20,...,25,150}{%% foreach 1 % %%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
\draw[help lines, densely dashed] (0,0) -- (\w:\r) coordinate(X) node[midway, below, sloped, inner sep=1pt]{$\w^\circ$};
\draw[help lines,] (X) circle[radius=1pt];
%
\draw[name path=C, help lines] (X) circle[radius=\r];

\draw[] (0,0) circle[radius=\R];

\node[regular polygon, draw, help lines, 
regular polygon sides=\n,
minimum size=2*\R,
](pol){};


\pgfmathtruncatemacro\t{0.5*\n+1}% "n/2-Test"

\foreach \k in {1,...,\n}{%% foreach 2 %
\node[] at (pol.corner \k){\k};% show edges
%
% Diagonals
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\m{0.5*\n+\k}
\ifnum\k<\t
\draw[name path=D, help lines,] (pol.corner \k) -- (pol.corner \m) 
    node[near end, above, sloped]{\k-\m}% show diagonal no. 
    ;


% Problem here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\path[name intersections={of=C and D, name=S}];
\coordinate[label=\k] (S\k) at (S-1); 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\shade[shading=ball, ball color=blue] (S\k) circle (0.075*\r);
\fi
}%% end of  foreach 2 %
\end{tikzpicture}
}%% end of  foreach 1 % %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}


Is a solution without the intersections library acceptable?
It's a little bit hard to follow how and what exactly happens with your code.
Anyway, by the default the order of the results is random-ish:

By default, the intersections are simply returned in the order that the intersection algorithm finds them. Unfortunately, this is not necessarily a “helpful” ordering.

The results can be sorted with the sort by key by one of the two paths. This can help … maybe. The order can then also be reversed by reversing the paths. Furthermore, a circle always starts at angle 0° and goes counter-clockwise. By drawing the circle as an arc you have more control over it and the returned order.
I fear, it would be better to find the points mathematically as the intersection between a circle and its tangent (certain angles when one of the dots is in the center of the big circle) will not always be found correctly.

For each diameter/spoke I'll find the projection of a point on the big circle onto the spoke, by rotating the coordinate system, this will be a projection onto the x axis (i.e. the cosine).
I'm overlaying the balls and use a border of 5pt for standalone so that the balls don't change the picture size when they lie on or near the four main compass points. They are probably better solutions for a real document to overcome this.
Code
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*\bigR{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro\smallR{\bigR/2}
\newcommand*\bigN{6}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\smallN{\bigN/2}
\foreach \w in {0, 5, ..., 359}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    big circle/.style={draw, thick},
    small circle/.style={draw, help lines},
    polygon/.style={draw=gray},
    spokes/.style={draw=gray, help lines},
    dot/.style={shading=ball, ball color=blue, radius=2pt}
  ]
  \coordinate (C) at (0,0);
  
  \path[polygon] plot[sharp cycle, samples at = {1, ..., \bigN}]
    (360/\bigN*\x:\bigR);
  \foreach \i in {1, ..., \bigN} \draw[spokes] (C) -- (360/\bigN*\i:\bigR);
  \path[small circle] ([shift=(\w:\smallR)]C) circle[radius=\smallR];
  \path[big circle] (C) circle[radius=\bigR];
  
  \foreach[count=\i from 0] \j in {1, ..., \smallN}
    \path[overlay, shift=(C), rotate=360/\bigN*\i, dot]
      ({cos(\w-360/\bigN*\i)*\bigR},0) circle[]
      node[below, rotate=-90-\w+360/\smallN*\i] {\footnotesize\j};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}

Output

With n = 20 → 10 balls.

I have now also created a solution without intersections.
But I was too lazy and determined the positions of the balls as corners of an n/2-polygon:
n=6:

n=26:

\documentclass[margin=3pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\R{2cm}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\r{0.5*\R}
\def\n{6}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\nh{0.5*\n}
%\def\w{33}% test

\foreach \w in {0,5,...,360}{%% foreach 1 % %%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize,
background rectangle/.style={draw=none, fill=yellow!33, rounded corners}, 
show background rectangle,
]
\draw[help lines, densely dashed] (0,0) -- (\w:\r) coordinate(X) 
   %node[midway, below, sloped, inner sep=1pt]{$\w^\circ$}
   ;
\fill[help lines] (X) circle[radius=1pt];
%
\draw[help lines] (X) circle[radius=\r];

\draw[] (0,0) circle[radius=\R];

% Outer Polygn
\node[regular polygon, draw, help lines, 
regular polygon sides=\n,
minimum size=2*\R,
](Pol){};

\foreach \k in {1,...,\n}{%% foreach 2 %
% Diagonals of Outer Polygon
\foreach \k in {1,...,\n}{
\draw[] (Pol.corner \k) -- (Pol.center); 
}

% Inner Polygon ===================
\node[regular polygon, draw, help lines, 
regular polygon sides=\nh, rotate=-90-\w,
minimum size=2*\r,
](pol) at (X){};
%
\foreach \s in {1,...,\nh}{%% foreach 3 %
\shade[shading=ball, ball color=blue] (pol.corner \s) circle[radius=0.0575*\r];
\draw[help lines] (pol.corner \s) -- (pol.center); 
}%% end of foreach 3 %
% ============================
}%% end of  foreach 2 %
\end{tikzpicture}
}%% end of  foreach 1 % %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}


I like it. Let PGF/TikZ do all the hard work.  I've recently watched a Numberphile video on that topic and had projection/cosine on my mind.

\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
%==================
\def\r{2}\def\n{12}
%\begin{animateinline}[controls,autoplay,palindrome,loop]{8}
%\multiframe{360}{i=1+1}{
\foreach \i in {1,...,360}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[join=round,cap=round,color=red]
\path
(0:0) coordinate (O)
(\i:2*\r) coordinate (A)
($(O)!.5!(A)$) coordinate (I)
\foreach \j in {0,...,\n}{(I)++(\j*360/\n-\i:\r) coordinate (M\j)}
;
\clip (O) circle (2*\r+1);
\draw[blue] 
(O) circle (2*\r)
\foreach \j in {0,...,\n}{(\j*180/\n:2*\r)--(180+\j*180/\n:2*\r)}
;
\draw[red] (I) circle (\r);
\foreach \j in {0,...,\n}\fill[ball color=orange] (M\j) circle (.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
%\end{animateinline}
\end{document}

